# Distance vector routing algorithm advertising

Tags: algorithm, vector, routes, distance

[image]

In such a network we assume distance vector routing algorithm used. If the link goes down from A to B, A will change its distance vector B and will advertise its neighbor C about that. The question is that since A uses node B to reach D, will A change its distance vector to D?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If A lost the link to B, A will set all the paths via B by infinity, and wait to recalculate the shortest paths by receiving new broadcast.

In your case, after A lost the link to B, it will set the distance vector `(via B to B)` and `(via B to D)` by infinty, and broadcast this to C. After C broadcasts it has `(via D to D) = 4` and `(via B to B) = 6` to A, A will recalculate and get the new shortest paths `(via C to D) = 6` and `(via C to B) = 8`.